# REGEX for phone number - Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to make a REGEX for a phone number validation that only allows:

7 digits (5557865) that's formatted exactly like the example.

I'm pretty unfamiliar with regex or else I would tackle this myself. Hopefully that is enough info let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: What example? .......

Comment: The one in the parentheses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example https://regex101.com/r/oZ2yQ0/1

```
\(\d{7}\)

\( matches the character ( literally
\d{7} match a digit [0-9]
    Quantifier: {7} Exactly 7 times
\) matches the character ) literally
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I should put this in the model for validation? I cant seen to get this to work.

Comment: This is right but you probably need some kind of anchor or boundary.

Answer (score 3):

If it is just to match 7 digit number, you can use \d{7} or [0-9]{7}.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I should put this in the model for validation? I cant seen to get this to work.

Comment: Cameron, if you are using a web framework like Ruby on Rails and need the syntax for that, that is important information that needs to be in your question.

Answer (score 1):

can be just with

```
/\d{7}/ #or
/\d{1..7}/ #or
/\d[0-9]{7}/
```

the **\d** matches digits and **{7}** the number of the digits.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to tackle this:

```
# Ensure the number consists entirely of seven digits, nothing else.
number.match(/\A\d{7}\z/)

# Remove all non-digit characters (\D) and test that the length is 7.
number.gsub(/\D/, '').length == 7

# Test that this is either NNN-NNNN or NNNNNNN.
number.match(/\A\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d\z/)
```

Normally you want to make your validation methods as lenient as possible while still ensuring things are valid.